# Express no longer qualifying routes after subdomain added

Tags: javascript, express, react-router

We had a nice little app that was functioning perfectly and then we got asked to turn it into something that others in our organization could leverage...  and that broke everything.  We had a simple express server with a few api routes as well as a react app being served.
Originally we would access our app using a url pattern like: https://our_team_name.company.com/app_name/

We had express listening to routes like:

// server.js:

```
import "./env";
import app from "app";
import { logger } from "@company/shared-code";

let fs = require("fs");
let https = require("https");

let privateKey = fs.readFileSync(`${process.env.CERT_HOME}/server.key`, "utf8");
let certificate = fs.readFileSync(`${process.env.CERT_HOME}/server.crt`, "utf8");
let credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };

let httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    logger.info("Application listening on port " + (process.env.PORT || 3000) + "!");
});
```

// app.js:

```
import express from "express";
import health from "./routes/health/health.js";

const app = express();
app.use("/app_name/rest/health", health);

app.use(express.static(path.join(process.cwd(), "build")));
app.get("/app_name/ui*", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd(), "build", "index.html"));
});
```

// health.js:

```
import express from "express";
import os from "os";
import Promise from "bluebird";

const disk = Promise.promisifyAll(require("diskusage"));
const health = express.Router();

health.get("*", async (req, res) => {
    const { available, total } = await disk.checkAsync(os.platform() === "win32" ? "c:" : "/");
    try {
        res.send({
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            results: [
                {
                    testName: "System",
                    status: "OK",
                    message: "System Information",
                    platform: os.platform(),
                    processing: {
                        architecture: os.arch(),
                        cpu: {
                            count: os.cpus().length,
                            cpus: os.cpus(),
                        },
                        avgLoad: os.loadavg(),
                    },
                    memory: {
                        totalMemory: (os.totalmem() / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + "GB",
                        freeMemory: (os.freemem() / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + "GB",
                    },
                    disk: {
                        available: (available / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + "GB",
                        total: (total / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + "GB",
                        percentFull: (((total - available) / total) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%",
                    },
                },
            ],
            status: "OK",
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(520).send({
        err,
        });
    }
});

export default health;
```

Express caught the "rest" routes (eg ***https://our_team_name.company.com/app_name/rest/health***) and served content, and it caught the "ui" routes and served index.html which had react router to handle the client side routes and everyone was happy.

In order to for us to provide the proper certs to new teams that leveraged this we got a new wildcard cert that covered *.technology.company.com/app_name/ so the next team could fork the repo and deploy without needing to obtain new certs...  great.

We congratulated ourselves on a job well done and deployed with this new configuration.  However upon navigation to https://our_team_name.technology.company.com/app_name/ it now appears that every route is served by get("/app_name/ui*")...  despite way too much time trying to debug this i've been unable to understand why my "rest" routes aren't qualified or even recreate this behavior over localhost.

Currently requesting ***https://our_team_name.technology.company.com/app_name/rest/health*** has a response of index.html and the health route is never called.

Has anyone experienced an issue like this?

UPDATE: added additional implementation details

Comment: Where are rest routes defined?  Please show us that code and how it relates to the above code.  Also, please supply an example of a specific URL that does not have the desired behavior and describe exactly what happens you request that URL.

Comment: Turns out this was an issue with the create-react-app service worker...

Comment: Then, to wrap up this question rather than leave it handing here indefinitely, you have two choices.  You can write your own separate answer (and accept it when timing allows) that explains what the problem was and how you fixed it or you can just delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The create-react-app service worker was trying to cache resources in an unexpected manner resulting in express not actually being called...  Solution was an update to the service worker